# How to calculate type I error for 6 classes?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics

I use python and sklearn. 
My dataset consists of 6 classes. I do not understand how to calculate the error I type.

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion= 'gini', max_leaf_nodes= 31 , max_depth= 9)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How to calculate the error I type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `classification_report`? Assuming your test data and labels are called `X_test` and `y_test`:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_pred = model.transform(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: I can get classification_report. But where exactly in it error  I type ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by that! In statistical hypothesis testing a type 1 error is wrongly rejecting the null hypothesis. That's a sort of false positive, so perhaps you're looking for "precision"?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was not sure that this is "precision".